# Jquery dropdown menu hiding behind jquery button

Tags: jquery, html, css

As suggested in the answers to many similar questions on here, I've played around with the `z-index`, but had no luck. Notice the `z-index` in the `container` class in CSS; this has had no effect however. It's just a basic demo at the moment so the html is only a basic table.

Below is my code.

When a person clicks on the first field on each row a button is inserted to the side of this field - so in between fields one and two; this drop down menu then sits behind the button on row two etc - the problem.

Update - helpfully somebody has provided a working jfiddle below for my full code - thank you; although the button produced by clicking in the first field on each row is now below, not adjacent, for some reason, the z index does appear to be working.  So the question for more experienced people than me is, why is it working in jquery and not in xampp?

```js
// create button 
var idcheck = $(this).next().attr('id');

if (idcheck) {
  // do nothing atm
} else {
  $(this).children().attr('size', '13');
  $(this).after("<td id = 'customDropdown' class='btn'><span class='valueHolder'>Add</span></td>");
}
});

//drop down menu
var div = '<div class="container"><div class="option">Option 1</div><div class="option">Option 2</div><div class="option">Option 3</div></div>';
$(this).append(div);
```

```css
#customDropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 192px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.btn {
  /* irrelevant except for: */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        4
      </td>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="item">
            <input type="text">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text">
          </td>


Output as shown inspect element on Firefox:

<td id = "customDropdown" class = "btn>
<span class = "valueHolder">Add</span>
<div class = "container">
<div class = "option">Option 1></div>
etc </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I've put your code in a snippet - you can now see why it doesn't work as your JS syntax is incorrect as it has mis-matched braces and brackets.

Comment: Thanks; although I don't really understand "snippets".  It's been working in Xampp; and the above is only a partial part of the script that is working Xampp; it's just when i copied all that into jquery it wasn't working... thanks anyway

Comment: Where should I add a print screen of the inspect element on firefox?  And to answer your question, as the print screen would show, the container sits beneath the button, in between <td> and </td> there are no surrounding divs.

Comment: this is the relevant ouput (in question above)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/az5ryLot/  ... this isn't working but it contains the code which for some reason is working xampp

Comment: You can diagnose JS problems by looking at the errors in the console. In the case of that fiddle the erros says `$ is undefined`, which means you haven't included jQuery. Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/az5ryLot/1/

Comment: Excellent; did you change anything else by the way?  Despite the button now being in slightly the wrong place it nevertheless it now over, not behind, the button below...

Comment: that's interesting; taking the z index out of the container your fiddle seems to make the difference; why wouldn't it be working in xampp?